# How do I change the font color of a specific text bound to a model on a Razor page?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net-core, razor-pages

I am building an ASP.NET Core web application and would like to style certain text in my result table a different color than the rest of the table. For example:

[image: The desired result]

I am trying to do this in JavaScript but seem to be running into issues because the data is generated on the page from the model after a Search button is clicked with the selected parameters. Here is what I have in my HTML Razor page:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.SecurityLog)
{
  <tr>
  <td style="width:7% !important" id="eventType">
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventType.Name)
  </td>
  <td style="width:9% !important">
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactName)
  </td>
}
```

Here is the JavaScript code that is also on the Razor page:

```
 var text = document.getElementById("searchString");
 var str = text.innerHTML;
 var reg = /RL Solution Required/ig;

 var toStr = String(reg);
 var search = (toStr.replace('\/g', '|')).substring(1);
 var searches = search.split("|");

 if (searches.indexOf("RL Solution Required") > -1) {
    str = str.replace(/RL Solution Required/g, '<span style="color:red;">R/L Solution Required</span>');
 }
 document.getElementById("searchString").innerHTML = str;
```

I am trying to get the RL Solution Required font to be in red. I am not experiencing any errors with this code but the font is black.
Thanks in advance and any help is appreciated.

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the criteria for changing color? Could this just be accomplished with CSS's `nth` selector?

Comment: @JohnPavek The criteria is if the EventType contains the words 'RL Solution Required', display it in red. I am not familiar with the nth selector but I will look into that now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use Javascript for this.  Just use Razor.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.SecurityLog)
{
  <tr>
  <td style="width:7% !important">        
      @{
        string eventType = item.EventType.Name;
      }
      @if(eventType.Contains("RL Solution Required"){
        <span style="color:red;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => eventType)</span>
      }else{
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => eventType)
      }          
  </td>
  <td style="width:9% !important">
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactName)
  </td>
}
```

Comment: This worked perfect! I didn't realize how I could do that in Razor! Thank you @RC Cola.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experiencing could be for a number of reasons.

For example: I see you using !important in some of your css. If you have another span tag with a color property that also is set to !important, it will be overriding the color that you are inserting into your html.

The best thing to do would be to inspect the element in a browser's dev tools and try modifying the css to properly update the color there. If you can get it to update there and describe what you have changed, it will be easier to narrow down the specific issue that you are having here.

If you ARE able to modify the element properly using css and something needs changed in your generated code, you may be able to just go from there and figure it out.

Comment: I can not change the CSS with developer tools because I am unable to access the data in the data rows using $("#eventType").val(). I am having a hard time accessing the data because it is being dynamically generated via the model. Dev tools only let me style the static content on the screen.